# How do I have to modify the css to make links not to overlap when resizing the browser window?

Tags: css, hyperlink, overlapping

I have links in my website and when I resize the browser window, they overlap. I have tried using some media query but didn't succeed.

I tried using max-width on my navigation div, but it only looked dumb in the browser. The text div shrinked properly but the navigation div was just long. When using a mobile device, it looked pretty sharp but...

Code of my front page including the navigation div (named #navi).

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Site title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="fi">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="tyyli.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="runko">
    <div id="logo"></div>

    <div id="navi">
      
    <a class="navi" href="index.php">Frontpage</a></div>

    <div id="teksti">
    Text here.</div>
```

And here is the navigation's css:

```css
#runko {
max-width: 960px;
margin: auto;
background:none;

}

#teksti {
width: 100%;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #715C3C;
min-height:50%;
background:#d3f0ff;
text-align: justify;
margin: auto;
margin-bottom: 5px;
padding: 5px;
line-height: 2.0;
}


h1{
font-family: 'Mirza', cursive;
font-size:50px;
padding:1px;
margin:1px;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

#teksti h1 {
border-bottom: 1px dotted #316e66; 
color: #316e66;
font: 30px/30px 'Aref Ruqaa', serif;
margin: 0 0 18px;
text-transform:none; 
}

#teksti h2 {

color: #316e66;
font: 25px/25px 'Aref Ruqaa', serif;
margin: 0 0 18px;
text-transform:none; 
}

#logo {
background-image: url(kuvat/kuvalogopieni.png);
width: 520px;
height:320px;
margin: auto;
}

#navi {

width:100%;
margin:10px;
}

a.navi:link, a.navi:visited, a.navi:active {
margin: 4px;
padding:6px;
border:none;
display:block;
background-image: url(kuvat/bg-navigation.png);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
font-size:17px;
color:#08496b;
display:inline-block;
letter-spacing:2px;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;

}

a.navi:hover{
background-image: url(kuvat/bg-navi-hover.png);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
color:#ffffff;
}
```

[Problem shown here in the picture also.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dY6sh.jpg)

Comment: Make the links `inline-block` instead of `inline`.

Comment: Please update your question so that it shows *all* your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).